# How to calculate if NSString is too long for drawInRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, word-wrap

I am adding a variaty of different lengths to a pdf I am creating and I used the following code to write txt to the pdf.

```
if (subLocationCellTextString.length > 0) {
                NSString *areaLocationString = @"Area Location:";
                [areaLocationString drawInRect:CGRectMake(290.0, 195.0, 100.0, 25.0) withAttributes:blackAttributes];
                // line
                [self drawLineDarkGreyRect:290.0 StartB:215.0 FinishA:555.0 FinishB:215.0];

                [subLocationCellTextString drawInRect:CGRectMake(382.0, 195.0, 200.0, 20.0) withAttributes:grayAttributes];
            }
```

There are a few occasions where subLocationCellTextString is too long for the drawInRect that I make. I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the size of the NSString so if it is too large then I can wordwrap to a second line.

Comment: Use the `NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
 CGRect rect = [areaLocationString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth,CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:blackAttributes context:nil];
    if (rect.size.height > yourheight){
        //Too long
    }
```